# C++ : One way jump to functions... any alternative?

Tags: c++

I am a student and learning c++. Last year i made is simple project for my skul and now i realise that to make it user friendly, i made multiple calls from one function to another without thinking of the stack and the memory leak it would cause. Basically, Its a student database management system and I have made one function corresponding to one screen i.e. one function for menu, one for adddata, modify data and so on. The code is big so i have pasted a small portion . Just observe how I first called add1() from menu() and then again menu() from add1()...

```
 `//***************************STUDENT DATABASE***********************************

void add1(){

     system("CLS");
     char ch;
     int i=no; 
     do{   
     i++;  
     cout<<"\nName : ";
     cin.ignore ( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
     getline (cin,s[i].name);      
     cout<<"\nClass : ";
     cin>>s[i].cl;
     cout<<"\nRollno : ";
     cin>>s[i].rollno;
     cout<<"\nMarks in";
     s[i].m.avg=0;
     for(int j=0;j<maxsb;j++)
     {
                            cout<<"\n"<<subject[j]<<": ";
                            cin>>s[i].m.s[j];
                            s[i].m.avg+=(s[i].m.s[j]/maxsb);
                            }
     no=i;
     cout<<"\nPress 'n' for next and 'b' to exit : "; 
     cin>>ch;
     cout<<"\n***********************************************************************";
     }while(ch=='n'); 
     menu(); //calling menu() again from this function...
}
                             //*************        
void menu(){
     system("CLS");
     int n,flag=0;
     do
     {
     cout<<"1.ADD DATA\n2.VIEW REPORT\n3.MODIFY DATA\n4.DELETE DATA\n5.SORT DATA\n6.GO BACK TO PREVIOUS MENU\n";
     cout<<"PLEASE ENTER YOUR CHOICE(enter corresponding integer): "; 
     cin>>n;
     switch(n)
     { case 2: report();break;
       case 1: add1();break;
       case 3: modify();break;
       case 4: del();break;
       case 5: sort();break;
       case 6: first(); 
       default:cout<<"PLEASE ENTER A VALID CHOICE";system("CLS");flag=1;
       }
       }
       while(flag==1);                              
     }
                              //**************

void first()
{
     system("CLS");
     int n,flag=0;
     cout<<"\t\t\tSoftware for Teachers";
     cout<<"\n\n1.Student Database\n\n2.Play Game\n\n3.Calculator";
     cout<<"\n\nEnter your choice: ";
     do{
     flag=0;
     cin>>n;
     switch(n)
     {
              case 1:{  if(flag2==0) 
                        {           setting();
                                    flag2=1;
                                    }
                        menu(); }
                   break;
              case 2: game();
                   break;
            //  case 3: calculator();
               //    break;
              default: cout<<"\nPlz enter a valid choice \n\n Enter your choice again:  ";flag=1;
              }
     }
     while(flag);
}

//******************************************************************************
int main()
{
    int temp;
    first();
    cin>>temp;
}
`
```

Such jumping from one function to another and then never returning back has been done several times in my code, which i now realize, kills the stack..
I have googled much and i know that firstly its not possible to do one way jump randomly from one function to another and combining everything in a single function and using goto to jump from one block to another isnt a very good idea(its actually worse!!). So, my question is, is there a better way i can achieve this task?? (this here means the thing m trying to do in above code i.e. the user friendliness of this program)

Thanks

Comment: You should restructure your code so that you don't need this kind of dual recursion. You should have a loop that prints the menu then calls the selected function, which returns, and then the loop iterates again.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Just the stack space? what about the heap space used by the function? And why just mentioning dynammically allocated calls for the heap, not for the stack?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Heap allocation is not the issue here. The issue is a potential stack overflow due to recursive calls.

Comment: @Zaibis Dynamic allocated memory is not on the stack, it's on the heap. The stack used by a function call is always rolled back when the function returns, which is why you can't e.g. return pointers to local variables.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg And exactly that is WRONG! you can't know where the implementation it self puts its data on to. As the standard just tells about storage type classes and object lifetimes. So the implementation is allowed to put even automatic data on the heap and allocated data on the stack if it would like to because of optimization interests.

Comment: @Zaibis While technically you are correct, I have never in my almost 25 years of C and C++ programming come across a compiler or platform that does not store local data on the stack and dynamic (`malloc`/`new`/etc) on the "heap". What I *do* know is that any memory area designated for local variables will be automatically "unallocated" when the function returns. And using the stack for local variables *is* the optimization, because all the compiler has to do is adjust a register, instead of calling functions for the allocations/deallocations.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I can't proof it right now, but I remember that I have read about a system where the compiler may choose to place allocated space on to stack. This may happen if the compiler detected the variable is only accessed in a specific level of scope. And the other way round I'm not even that sure, but I also got  left in my mind there were also reasons why the compiler could want to put theese local variables on to the heap if there are multiple instances of  it which are identically used. (But as I said, abotu the second point I'm not even sure anymore.)

Comment: @Zaibis That is more probable than the other way around.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of calling `menu()` or `first()` to return to the previous menu, use `return`. For example in the  `menu()` function:

```
   case 6: return;
```

This means that the control will return to the calling function right after the function call. For example when you return from `add1` to `menu` the execution will continue in the loop that asks for choices.

Answer (score 1):

Just enclose your menu() (either inside or outside the) function in a loop, and return normally from your add1 function.

```
void add1(){

    …..

    }while(ch=='n'); 
    return; <--------------
}

void menu(){
    while(true) <------------------
    {
    system("CLS");
    int n,flag=0;
    do
    {
    cout<<"1.ADD DATA\n2.VIEW REPORT\n3.MODIFY DATA\n4.DELETE DATA\n5.SORT DATA\n6.GO BACK TO PREVIOUS MENU\n";
    cout<<"PLEASE ENTER YOUR CHOICE(enter corresponding     integer): "; 
     cin>>n;
    switch(n)
   { case 2: report();break;
     case 1: add1();break;
     case 3: modify();break;
     case 4: del();break;
     case 5: sort();break;
     case 6: return; <-------------------
     default:cout<<"PLEASE ENTER A VALID CHOICE";system("CLS");flag=1;
      }
     }
     while(flag==1);                              
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just let the handlers functions ( ie `add1()` ) to return to the main, that will call `menu()` again in a loop until you ask for exit.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever played arcade games on consoles, such as Mario? In such games we have multi-level menus (menus with submenus; one menu per screen). Hope, that it is what you want to achieve.

In computer games, typically, we implement such menus (states) with a stack data structure (LIFO).

- You wrap your menu screens (states) into objects. All resources initialized in constructor and all cleanup happens in destructor, so no leaks.

  ```
  class IState
  {
  public:
      virtual ~IState() {}
      virtual void Apply() = 0;
  };

  class MainMenuState : public IState
  {
  public:
      MainMenuState() { /*Here goes resources allocation*/ }
      virtual ~MainMenuState() {  /*Here goes resources freeing*/ }
      virtual void Apply() override { /*Here goes menu rendering*/ }
  };

  class SettingsMenuState : public IState
  {
  public:
      SettingsMenuState() { /*Here goes resources allocation*/ }
      virtual ~SettingsMenuState() {  /*Here goes resources freeing*/ }
      virtual void Apply() override { /*Here goes menu rendering*/ }
  };
  ```
- You store states in stack

  ```
  std::stack<IState> states;
  ```
- When user must see new menu you push state:

  ```
      states.push(MainMenuState()); // initial menu

      if (userWantsToSettings)
      {
          states.push(SettingsMenuState()); // second level
      }
  ```
- When user want go back, you pop state

  ```
      if (userWantsGoBack)
      {
          states.pop();
      }
  ```
- Sometimes (for games, it is once per frame, for console app it can be once user presses a button) you call `Update()`, to render topmost menu:

  ```
      void Update()
      {
          states.top().Apply();
      }
  ```

Refs:

[What is the best way to make a main menu system?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2499/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-main-menu-system)

[How should I structure my menu / game loop?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4911/how-should-i-structure-my-menu-game-loop)

Hope it helps. Happy coding! =)